# Why doesn't firebase auth support httponly cookie persistence?

Tags: firebase, cookies, firebase-authentication, jwt, httponly

As I know, storing jwt tokens in local storage/session storage is not secure because it can be accessed with javascript (XSS attacks), so the secure way is to store it in httpOnly cookie.
So why does Firebase auth provide every persistence method except the httpOnly one?

Comment: I'm wondering just the same.

Comment: "If you are using Firebase Hosting + Cloud Functions, __session is the only cookie you can store, by design. This is necessary for us to be able to efficiently cache content on the CDN -- we strip all cookies from the request other than __session."